# Can't install sdkman on Mac OS

Tags: sdkman

I am running Mac OS High Sierra and trying to install sdkman like so:

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

I get no messages returned, but am simply returned to the terminal prompt:

```
$
```

If I try:

```
sdk version
```

I get:

```
sdk: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

This was due to CURL not being able to run in HTTPS mode.  Had to use BREW to install a new version of CURL with SSL enabled.  SDKMAN is now installed.

Answer (score 1):

I did this to get it working

1. curl "https://get.sdkman.io"  > sdk.sh
2. chmod +x sdk.sh
3. edited the script to not use secure connection
   change curl -s "${SDKMAN_SERVICE}/candidates/all"
   to  curl  "${SDKMAN_SERVICE}/candidates/all"
4. bash sdk.sh