# Unable to install sdkman on macos

Tags: bash, macos, sdk, sdkman

I am unable to install sdkman on my macos. I referred [sdkman install](https://sdkman.io/install) and [Can't install sdkman on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165367/cant-install-sdkman-on-mac-os). Still, I am missing something. Can someone please help me ? I am new to MacOS and sdkman.

When I go to bash terminal and type `curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash` , it prints message failed to write body on terminal and opens my bash profile. What is that I am supposed to do next? I tried to follow steps mentioned at above urls, even used `source` as suggessted but I guess something is missing. I actually never write anything in bash profile, so `source` would not even do anything. I did multiple attempts using what I found online but `sdk version` never gives any output, it kept saying `sdk command not found`. I found online that I needed to upgrade curl, I even did that still no success.  Can someone please write / explain steps for me that I am missing? I would appreciate it. I did search online, but either steps are not clear or I am not getting something right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks more likely that the piped bash closes the read pipe before the previous curl finishes writing the whole page. When you issue `curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash`, as soon as the piped bash has what it wants, it will right away close the input stream from the previous curl. But the cURL doesn’t really expect this and throws a “failed writing body” error. You might want to try piping the stream through an intermediary program that always reads the whole page before feeding to bash. For instance, you can try something like this (running tac twice before piping to bash):

```sh
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | tac | tac | bash
```

tac is a Unix program that can  concatenate and print files in reverse. In this case, it reads the entire input page and reverses the line order (hence we run it twice). Because it has to read the whole input to find the last line, it will not output anything to bash until cURL is finished. bash will still close the read stream when it gets what it needs, but it will only affect tac, which doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The error writing body does not appear now. But when I use the curl command with tac , it opens bash profile, now what I am supposed to do, thats my question now. The instructions aren't really that clear on the web links I am following. Web link says, `source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`  , even if I enter that command on terminal, nothing happens.